# After a power failure I can't log in from the log in box and when I use the terminal (control alt F1), I can log in but nothing happens

Tags: login

When I log in via terminal I get the following messages:
Even if I tried startx

xauth: unable to write authority file ...

fatal server error

could not write pid to lock file in ...and all things I don't know about.

I have important files on there and hope somebody can help.

Comment: After a power failure; I tend to boot *live* media and perform file-system checks (ie. `fsck`) as well as check out the health of my drives etc (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools) so I'm aware of issues advance of them being a problem. The `fsck` if it detects & fixes issues will mean you an normally login next boot (power failure means the system didn't cleanly shutdown; `fsck` can fix some of those issues)

Comment: what do you mean with live media? A ISO DVD or what?

Comment: Ubuntu installation media and using the *Try Ubuntu* is what I meant. It doesn't need to be the same release you've got installed; but it's better if more recent (and thus include later software with any security fixes applied).   *live* media is loaded from the boot media & runs entirely in RAM why it's considered *live*, when you reboot it's gone except for changes you save to disk (ie. `fsck` works; take note to `fsck` your real disk partitions & not the boot/live media itself; GUI tools can be used to perform `fsck` or file-system checks if you're not familiar with command line tools).

Comment: Using Try Ubuntu has given me access to my harddrives but not to my desktop where I had a few folders with important files. Also by typing fsck in any terminal window is no success. Maybe I am doing something wrong, I have not much knowledge about Linux except how to use it.

Comment: If you've booted a Ubuntu Desktop; I'd suggest using `gparted` or `gnome-disk-utility` to perform *file-system* checks.  A `fsck` command requires you to provide the path to your installed system's drive/partitions.  Note:  As I don't know your release; this advice is generic (ie. adjust for your *unstated* OS & release)

Comment: Thanks for your answers but this is unfortunately too complicated for me as I do not understand what you mean and I can't find anything on my my computer. Also I can't add a pic or so here.

Comment: I can log in via terminal and it says: Welcome to Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux5.4.0-89-lowlatency x86_64) After that it shows weblinks for documentations. 13 updates can be applied immediately. To see these additional updates run: apt list --upgradable. That was it and I don't know what to do further...

Comment: After that all I typed in startx and the following appeared: xauth: unable to write authority file /tmp/ serverauth.pTsQYNqxuX-n, xauth: unable to write authority file /home/werkstatt/.,Xauthority-n, xauth: unable to write authority file /home/werkstatt/.Xauthority-n.,  EE, Fatal server error: (EE) Could not write pid to lock file in /tmp/.tX1-lock, (EE) (EE) Please consult the X.ORG Foundation Support at http://wiki.x.org, for help, (EE), xinit: giving up, xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused, Xinit: server error